# Using ApplicationContext inside @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Regarding the below code:

1. When *ServicesConfig1* is loaded, can I be sure that *ApplicationContext* was already loaded and never will be **NULL**?
2. When *Bean1* is loaded how can I be sure that *Bean2* was already loaded? let's say that I can't move *Bean2* declaration to *ServicesConfig1*

   I tested it and  *ApplicationContext* wasn't **NULL**, but I just want to be sure that it not loaded in random order, so my test now passed by next time will fail.

   f

   ```
   @Configuration
       public class ServicesConfig1
       {


           @Inject
           private ApplicationContext ctx;



           @Bean
           public Bean1 bean1() 
           {

               Bean2 bean2 = ctx.getBean(Bean2.class);
               ....
           }


       }


       @Configuration
       public class ServicesConfig2
       {


           @Bean
           public Bean2 bean2() 
           {
               return new Bean2();
           }

       }
   ```

Comment: If you want ServiceConfig2 do be configured before ServiceConfig1 , You can use `@Order` and specify the ordering number at the class Level. You can also use `@DependsOn`

Comment: Don't use the `ApplicationContext` to get `Bean2`, inject it directly into the `bean1` factory method. `public Bean1 bean1(Bean2 bean2)`

Comment: Order is for defining priority for beans with the same name, so if there are 2 beans with the same name, the one with the higher Order will be loaded.
it's not the case here. Maybe DependsOn.

Comment: There's very little reason to ever use `ApplicationContext` to retrieve a bean.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to inject `ApplicationContext` here at all.
Think of `ApplicationContext` as a more container specific bean, which allows more fine-grained control over beans lifecycle and which you do not need in most cases.

For your concrete case you can use simple dependency injection.

```
@Configuration
public class ServicesConfig1{
    @Bean
    public Bean1 bean1(Bean2 bean2){
        ....
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ServicesConfig2 {
    @Bean
    public Bean2 bean2() {
        return new Bean2();
    }
}
```

By passing `bean2` as an argument to `bean1` you signaling to the DI container that for constructing it you have a dependency on `bean2`, so the container will look if `bean2` is already been instantiated and if not it will create it and then inject it for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@DependsOn`

```
@Configuration
    public class ServicesConfig1
    {


        @Inject
        private ApplicationContext ctx;



        @Bean
        @DependsOn(value = "Bean2")
        public Bean1 bean1() 
        {

            Bean2 bean2 = ctx.getBean(Bean2.class);
            ....
        }


    }


    @Configuration
    public class ServicesConfig2
    {


        @Bean
        public Bean2 bean2() 
        {
            return new Bean2();
        }

    }
```

Even better solution would be to take `Bean2` as argument for bean1 function. this way spring will initialize and inject it into your function.

```
        @Bean  
        public Bean1 bean1(Bean2 bean2) 
        {
            ...
         }
```

Comment: how does this answer the questions above?

Comment: @Reimeus This way,  before the code enters bean1 declaration, it will initialize Bean2. And tha tis exactly what the question is. Can you explain why this wouldn't work

Comment: The `@DependsOn` is unnecessary. `getBean` will force initialization of `bean2`.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis  getBean will force it, so here comes my first question, can I always be sure that ApplicationContext were already initialized?

Comment: @user3132197 Yes, the `ApplicationContext` is the original Spring object. That's what is currently processing your `@Configuration` class.